# Access alias of a node programatically using Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, pathauto

I am creating a custom block programatically, there i need to display a node title and link to it, I have accomplished the displaying of node and title.

How do i link the node to its alias, each node in my application has an alias.

How do i access the alias ion my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function:

```
drupal_lookup_path('alias',"node/" . $node->nid);
```

to get your node URL alias by node id.

Then just create the link with `l` -function.